# How to simulate a window resize in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm relatively new to React (and Javascript, for that matter) so please bear with me.

To put my question shortly: how do i trigger a resize event on my window/component in React?

Now below is a little more context, which may actually prove that i'm asking a wrong question here.

I'm trying to create a small app with several tabs. The  component is taken from BlueprintJS framework. The content of these tabs is loaded using a javascript API, which in turn uses RESTful requests to a remote application. The content that will be rendered in my tabs is some tables and charts.

**Here is a caveat**. The actual rendering of those tables and charts is performed by the javascript API i have to use, not by my React app. I have to pass an ID of a  to the API, and it will render returned content into that .

**The problem**: Only the content of the default active tab is rendered correctly. If i switch to any other tab of my React application, the content is not rendered. HOWEVER if i resize the window the content is rendered instantly (i believe this is handled by the javascript API i'm using). Also if i update parameters of the currently active tab to make the API load updated content from the remote application, the content is also rendered in the active tab.

So i figured if i can simulate the resize event when switching between tabs i can get my content to render.

I tried setting a conditional class on my  as depending on whether the current tab is active or not:

```
<div className={this.state.SelectedTabId === "tab1" ? "container" : "hidden"}>
```

where "container" and "hidden" have different width configured in CSS file, but this doesn't help. I also tried to directly manipulate the DOM (at least as a test) but even that didn't make a difference:

```
let e1 = document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0];
            e1.width = e1.scrollWidth - 1;
            renderedElement.resize(); //this is an API method which is supposed to re-render the content it returns
```

Comment: Can you show some of your code? For example how you perform the rest api fetching ..

Comment: @froston, I'm not making a rest call directly but using a javascript API.

The application I am using is JasperReports Server. It hosts a bunch of reports which i'm trying to pull using javascript API called VIsualize.js. The way it works is you call a function named "visualize", and then request and render resources from JasperReports Server application with a callback function. An API call i'm using looks like this:

visualize(

Comment: Sorry, got my previous comment truncated. An API call i'm using looks like this:

`visualize(
   {
      //authentication object
   }, function(v) {
      v.report({
         resource: "/path/to/resource/in/application",
         container: "#container",
         error: function(e) {
           console.log(e);
      }
      });
   }
);`

Comment: OK the comment formatting does not work the way i want it. You can find a simple example of the API i'm using here:
https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/mootools/1.5.2/TIBCOSoftware/JS-visualize/tree/master/ahv-embed/basic-render/

My request looks very similar